# This auto submit form doesn't work (sometimes!)

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, form-submit

This is strange. This code works well when I open it directly --but if I run the web page that precedes it it doesn't. This code is a confirmation page that I want to jump in a checkout process -I have all my fields, and I don't need to ask the user again for confirmation, so I send her to checkout directly, sending all the values of the fields.

Again, when I arrive to this page from another form post it doesn't work --despite no other field or object sent to this page is called like the form--. Any ideas?

```
<?php include 'security.php' ?>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />    
<title>Secure Acceptance - Payment Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="payment.css"/>
</head>

<body>

<?php
    foreach($_REQUEST as $name => $value) {
        $params[$name] = $value;
    }
?>
<p>Redirecting to Secure Server...</p>

<form action="https://testsecureacceptance.cybersource.com/pay" method="post" id="formulario" name="formulario" />

    <?php
        foreach($params as $name => $value) {
            echo "<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"" . $name . "\" name=\"" . $name . "\" value=\"" . $value . "\"/>\n";
        }

        echo "<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"signature\" name=\"signature\" value=\"" . sign($params) . "\"/>\n";
    ?>

<input type="submit" id="boton" name="boton" value="Ir a Checkout >>"/>

</form>

<script type = "text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('formulario').submit();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try to use 'setTimeout(function(){ /* your code */ , 1000}', the form might not ready when javascript is rendered

Comment: Does one of your `$params` have a `$name` of "submit"?  If so, you have hijacked the document.form.submit function and it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JavaScript `setTimeout` method to delay the submit function while page loads or you can also use jQuery to wait until documents load and after that you can fire form submit function:
JS:

```
setTimeout(function(){
 document.getElementById('formulario').submit();
},1000);
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#formulario').submit();
})
```

Comment: Since the javascript function call is at the end of the document body, you don't need to do this.